# cancel paypal subscription from my cart

Tags: paypal

as stated here: [Detecting Paypal Subscription Cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092358/detecting-paypal-subscription-cancellation?answertab=active#tab-top) api can be used to detect a paypal subscription cancellation. what about the opposite? using magento, i have code that creates the paypal subscription but when i cancel the subscription (in the cart), the cancellation is not passed to paypal and i must then go to paypal to cancel.

it would be great to avoid the extra step of double canceling and just only have to cancel from my cart (as admin and as customer via api sent to paypal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API to cancel "I-" profiles.  As far as if Magento supports this, or if there is a plugin that you can use I don't know of one off hand.  However, it is possible.  All that needs to happen is that your cart just needs to make API call.

Comment: i did notice the "l-" qualification in reading some threads. mine is L...would that be the same as l ? > 
e.g. this is mine:
> [L_NAME1] => product name
> [L_QTY1] => 1
> [L_AMT1] => 29.95

Comment: The "L" that you are referring to is for the line items.  You should have a profile id for each profile, and it would look something like "I-3243FDW32".  This is what I was referring to.  As long as your profile starts with "I-" and not "S-", you can use this API.

Comment: ok thanks yes my profiles are: Profile ID I-UT6RV13CVFUK In this case, i suppose its a magento limitation that it does not happen by default

Comment: so if this is available what cart or script actually uses it?

Comment: I don't know of any 3rd party carts or scripts off hand.